# Do you know of orthogonal-polynomial families with complex measure on the square? I'm just looking for family names to read up on

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, orthogonal-polynomials

I'm looking for the name(s) of a family or families of polynomials whose normalization and orthogonality are defined by integrals (inner product) over the complex square $\{u+iv\, |\, u, v \in [-1,1]\}$.  It would be helpful if the inner product emphasized parts of the square, such as the center or the boundaries, like Chebyshev does in the reals: i.e., using a weighted integral.

An example for the complex unit disk: The Zernicke's are such a family (with uniform weighting over the disk, as it happens).  Only I want the square.

I know we can construct such a family using Gram-Schmidt.  I am hoping someone has already done that work and written about it, especially proving theorems that might help to select among families (i.e., among weighting functions).  This seems like a classic 19th-Century exercise, but I have not found useful references so far.

I just need a *name* to read about -- I hope.  Alternatively, a well recommended book that discusses several such families.

Comment: Do you want real or complex polynomials?  For real, could you just take the product $P_n(u) P_m(v)$ of [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)?

Comment: Alas, those products are not generally polynomials in u+iv.  I need polynomials in u+iv that are orthonormal on the square.